# Saving an object with date to user defaults - date won't be the same

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults, codable, jsondecoder

I am saving and restoring a simple struct that contains a date. The reason for using this string format is that RESTful API is returning this date format. Meaning that it shouldn't be changed for this code example below.

```
extension DateFormatter {

    static let yyyyMMdd: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

}

struct Person: Codable, Equatable {

    let birthDate: Date

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case birthDate
    }

}

func storePerson(_ person: Person) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.yyyyMMdd)
    guard let encodedPerson = try? encoder.encode(person) else {
        return
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedPerson, forKey: "savedPerson")
}

func fetchPerson() -> Person {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.yyyyMMdd)

    guard let savedPerson = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedPerson"),
        let person = try? decoder.decode(Person.self, from: savedPerson) else {
            fatalError()
    }

    return person
}

let person = Person(birthDate: Date())
storePerson(person)
let storedPerson = fetchPerson()

print("\(person == storedPerson)") // this will be false
print("\(person.birthDate)")
print("\(storedPerson.birthDate)") // same date as above, but with no minutes
```

Why is the date not the same? The encoder and decoder are using the same `dateEncodingStrategy`

Comment: you are not storing the time. If you would like to keep the date precision use the default dateEncodingStrategy `deferredToDate`

Comment: Using `.deferredToDate` will solve this code example, but I was using the date formatter since this object is also retrieved form a server, where the date in the JSON will be equal to `"date":"2019-06-11"`

Comment: Well You can simply treat it as a string

Comment: You should be using a separate `JSONDecoder` (or at least a separate `DateFormatter` for its decoding strategy) to decode a `Person` from a JSON response from your server and to encode that object when storing it locally or when decoding it from `UserDefaults`.

Comment: I ended up using the dateEncodingStrategy `.deferredToDate` for when saving to user defaults and `.formatted(DateFormatter.yyyyMMdd)` when decoding the response from the server. Thanks.

Comment: @José would you like me to post the first comment as an answer ?

Comment: @LeoDabus you can if you want. The solution ended up being a mix of your and Dávid's answer.